# window undefined error coming from testing library causing TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to test this logic inside a custom hook when window is undefined.

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    console.log('inside');
    return true;
}
  console.log('outside');
  return false;
};
```

Thus mocking window as follows and running following test.

```
import React from "react";
import { renderHook, act } from "react-hooks-testing-library";

const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(window, "window", "get");

afterEach(() => {
    windowSpy.mockRestore();
});

test("should return false when window is undefined", () => {
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => undefined);
    const { result } = renderHook(() => myHook("test"));
    expect(result.current).toBe(false);
});
```

When I run this test, window is undefined as expected but I end up with following error from `react-test-renderer.development.js`.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined: line 2352
```

When I look at that library below, during the if check, window is not undefined yet.

But by the time we get to windowEvent, window. is undefined.

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.dispatchEvent === 'function' && typeof document !== 'undefined' && typeof document.createEvent === 'function') {
    // .....
      var windowEvent = window.event; // This is the error. window undefined here.
    // .....
  }
}
```

Think safe to say the fix is not within this lib. But more on how I could mock without issues here.

How can I write the test so that I can test when window is undefined but not be affected by this lib error?

Full hook implementation for reference.

```
import React from "react";
import isWindowDefined from "../isWindowDefined";

export const isWindowDefined = () => window !== undefined;

const useMediaQuery = (query: string): boolean => {
  const getMatches = (query: string): boolean => {
    if (isWindowDefined()) {
      return window.matchMedia(query).matches;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const [matches, setMatches] = React.useState<boolean>(getMatches(query));

  const handleChange = () => {
    setMatches(getMatches(query));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const matchMedia = window.matchMedia(query);
    handleChange();

    matchMedia.addEventListener("change", handleChange);

    return () => {
      matchMedia.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);
    };
  }, [query]);

  return matches;
};

export default useMediaQuery;
```

Comment: You could mock a function `isWindowDefined` to return `true` or `false` within your tests. Then in the real code the implementation could be `() => window !== undefined`. That way you don't need to modify `window` in your tests, which the testing library seems to depend on

Comment: @byxor Could you show an example pls.

Comment: Why does your code rely on `window` at all, though? What are you _really_ trying to test for? (Because you're not interested in whether `window` exists, you want to know that for a reason. What is that reason?). Because instead of using `window`, you almost _certainly_ want to use [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis), which is a JS language construct that in browsers matches the `window` object but in Node matches the `global` object. Now you don't need to test for window, you just check if `globalThis.thatThingINeed` exists.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If window exists, I want to use window.MatchMedia for some media query operations. In the event for SSR, window could be undefined thus checking for it. Added the full hook above for reference.

Comment: Then directly check for that. `if (globalThis.MatchMedia) { ... }`. No need to check the existence of the browser-only `window` variable, use the universal `globalThis`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mock a function `isWindowDefined` to return `true` or `false` within your tests. That way you don't need to modify `window` in your tests, which the testing library seems to depend on.

For example.

Instead of checking `window` directly in your hook...

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  console.log('inside');
  return true;
}
console.log('outside');
return false;
```

You can call a function that performs the check for you:

```
import { isWindowDefined } from "path/to/window-util";

// ...

if (isWindowDefined()) {
  console.log('inside');
  return true;
}
console.log('outside');
return false;
```

Then in your tests, you can mock `isWindowDefined()` to return `true` or `false`, without the need to interact with any real `window` object:

```
import React from "react";
import { renderHook, act } from "react-hooks-testing-library";
import * as windowUtil from 'path/to/window-util';

// Keep track of the original function implementation so we can reset it after tests
const realIsWindowDefined = windowUtil.isWindowDefined;

afterEach(() => {
    windowUtil.isWindowDefined = realIsWindowDefined;
});

test("should return false when window is undefined", () => {
    windowUtil.isWindowDefined = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(false);
    const { result } = renderHook(() => myHook("test"));
    expect(result.current).toBe(false);
});
```

Then `isWindowDefined` can be implemented properly in the production code to do the actual `window` check:

```
// e.g. defined in module: window-util.js
export function isWindowDefined() {
    return typeof window !== "undefined"
}
```

Comment: I've replaced it as a function as suggested. But this doesn't seem to work. const isWindowDefined = jest.spyOn(window, "isWindowDefined"); isWindowDefined function is now in a separate file.

Comment: It works if I mock it at the top level. But unable to do the same at a per test level. jest.mock('../isWindowDefined', () =>
  jest.fn(() => false)
);

Comment: I don't have enough information about your project structure to give you the exact arguments for `jest.spyOn`. If `isWindowDefined` is being exported from a module, you can follow the instructions here to mock it: See https://www.chakshunyu.com/blog/how-to-mock-only-one-function-from-a-module-in-jest/

Comment: In what way are you unable to mock the implementation at the test level?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use modules.